# How to grant a snap permission to read the whole filesystem

Tags: permissions, snap

I've installed the mdview snap. It gives file not found errors for whatever reason. How to I set up snap permissions so that I can run mdview anywhere on the filesystem and have it load the file I give it without error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Install in devmode

`sudo snap install mdview --devmode`

then run as usual

`mdview file.md`

2. Run from inside the snap, bypassing confinement

`/snap/mdview/current/bin/mdview file.md`

3. Install the deb

The upstream project has instructions on their [readme](https://github.com/mapitman/mdview) detailing how to install the deb, which would run unconfined.

Comment: So I take it you can't grant permissions to an installed snap?

Comment: Option 2 would work with it already installed.